# StringIndexOutOfBoundsException when converting char[] read from BufferedReader in Android

Tags: android, bufferedreader, indexoutofboundsexception, stringindexoutofbounds

I'm trying to read JSON-Strings through a socket connection in an Android app, but suddenly started getting StringIndexOutOfBoundsExceptions that I can't explain(blocked out some identifiers in the package name):

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=10000; regionStart=0; regionLength=-1
    at java.lang.StringFactory.newStringFromChars(StringFactory.java:218)
    at **.***********.SocketHandler.listenForMessages(SocketHandler.java:48)
```

where (starting at line 45) SocketHandler.listenForMessages() reads

```java
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
char[] buffer = new char[READ_BUFFER];
int messageLength = reader.read(buffer, 0, READ_BUFFER);
String message = new String(buffer, 0, messageLength);
```

I haven't touched that part of the code - which worked without problems a few weeks ago - when I suddenly got this Exception even when upping the READ_BUFFER to way bigger than the received messages should be (10k here).

The indicators

```
length=10000; regionStart=0; regionLength=-1
```

make me assume the problem stems from reading an empty message, but I can't figure out why the problem didn't arise sooner then. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this:

```
int messageLength = reader.read(buffer, 0, READ_BUFFER);
```

With this:

```
int messageLength = reader.read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
regionLength=-1
```

I think you are hitting an end of file.

> Returns:
>       The number of characters read, or -1 if the end of the stream has been reached

[The docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html#read-char:A-int-int-)